# React ErrorBoundary doesn't work with render exceptions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-error-boundary

I implemented the React Error Boundaries as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

It works as expected when there are exceptions produced in function components, however, today I got a white screen and I just noticed that the exception came from the Render section of the component.

This is my ErrorBoundary component:

```
  export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {  
  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

Which is implemented as followed:

```
export default function App() {
 return (
 <ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildComponent />
 </ErrorBoundary>
);
}
```

ChildComponent:

```
interface Item {
      name: string;
      value: number;
   }

export const ChildComponent: React.FC = () => {
 const [collection, setCollection] = useState<Item[]>([]);
 
 return (
 <>
   <button
     onClick={() => console.log(collection[0].name)}>//this throws a console.error but the component keep mounted correctly
     Click
     {collection[0].name}//this throws a console.error and a white screen
   </button>
 </>
);
}
```

I'd like to know what could I do to handle this type of exceptions since it is inevitable to have these situations where there might be an error and a white screen is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ErrorBoundary` always renders the children when an error is caught, which ones again throws the same error.

You should conditionally render a different fallback UI component when there are errors.

```js
export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
   static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error) {
     return {
       error // set some state based on error
     }
   }
   render() {
     if (this.state.error) { // render fallback UI if error occured
       return (<div> an error occured - action </div>);
     }
     // render children only when there isn't an error
     return this.props.children;
   }
}
```